# Storing references in a map

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

I tried to store a `foo` object into a `std::reference_wrapper`, but I end up with a compiler error I don't understand.

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    std::map< int, std::reference_wrapper< foo > > my_map;
    foo a;
    my_map[ 0 ] = std::ref( a );
}
```

The compiler error is pretty lengthy, but it boils down to this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::reference_wrapper<foo>::reference_wrapper()’
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: std::reference_wrapper has no default constructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::reference_wrapper` is not default-constructible (otherwise it would be a pointer).

```
my_map[0]
```

creates, if `0` is not already a key in the map, a new object of the mapped type, and for this the mapped type needs a default constructor. If your mapped type is not default-constructible, use [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::ref(a)));
```

or [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
my_map.emplace(0, std::ref(a));
```