# How to store references as values in a std::map, and use operator overloading to access them?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap

I'm trying to use a `std::map` where the values are stored as references. I've written a template `Container` class that should manage this, but I'm encountering issues with the `Add()` method and operator overloading.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<typename Key, typename Value>
class Container {
public:
    void Add(const Key& key, Value& value) {
        mMapContainer[key] = value;
    }
    
private:
    std::map<Key, Value&> mMapContainer;
};

int main() {
    Container<int, std::string> mContainer;
    
    std::string value = "value";
    
    mContainer.Add(1, value);
    
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to store the values in the `std::map` as references, but as you might know, the `Add()` method isn't working as expected. How should I approach overloading `operator[]` and `operator=` to make this code functional?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363694/storing-references-in-a-map).

Comment: Do I have to use reference_Wrapper, can't I use it with operator overloading?

Comment: You should forget about making this code functional, because this entire concept goes against some fairly fundamental, core C++ principles. It's possible to make it work, but with a lot of pain, suffering, and tears. Instead, please describe the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about storing references in a map but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves storing references in a map. If the real problem gets described, then it's very likely that a proper solution can be devised, that's consistent with C++ fundamental concepts.

Comment: *Do I have to use reference_Wrapper, can't I use it with operator overloading?*  No, you do not have to use `reference_wrapper`.  Yes, you can do it with operator overloading.  To do it with operator overloading, you'll need to re-invent the reference_wrapper wheel.

Comment: A simple solution to the immediate problem is to store pointers. As in, `std::map<Key, Value*> mMapContainer;` and `void Add(const Key& key, Value& value) { mMapContainer[key] = &value; }`